# How to use recursion in Javascript to find the best possible Texas Hold 'em hand?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to come up with a quick way to evaluate a poker hand consisting of the usual five community cards and two cards unique to each player, so seven cards in total.

I read an [article](http://nsayer.blogspot.nl/2007/07/algorithm-for-evaluating-poker-hands.html) about a poker evaluator algorithm that uses recursion to first bring down the number of cards from seven to five, and then calculate the result from that.

I've had to use recursion at college a few times, but I can't see how it is applicable to this situation.

From what I understand, this guy is saying: We calculate the best possible five card result of each seven hand combination, so that'd imply that the whole evaluator logic would be contained within this recursive loop, but I don't see a) how this recursive loop will eventually reach its base case, and b) how to implement this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Source Code**

```
var suits = ['Clubs', 'Spades', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'];
var ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace'];
var combinations = ['Royal Flush', 'Straight Flush', 'Four of a Kind', 'Full House', 'Flush', 'Straight', 'Three of a Kind', 'Two Pair', 'One Pair'];
var deck = [];
var players = [new Player(), new Player()];
var table = [];

function Player()  {
    this.hand = [];
    this.result;
}

function Card(suit, rank)   {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.name = rank + ' of ' + suit;
}


function initDeck() {
    deck = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)   {
        for(var j = 0; j < 13; j++)   {
            deck.push(new Card(suits[i], ranks[j]));
        }
    }

}

function drawCard() {
    var randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    var drawnCard = deck[randNumber];
    deck.splice(randNumber, 1);

    return drawnCard;
}


function dealCards()    {
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)   {
        for(var j = 0; j < players.length; j++)   {
            var drawnCard = drawCard();
            players[j].hand.push(drawnCard);
        }
    }
}

function flop() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)   {
        var drawnCard = drawCard();
        table.push(drawnCard);
    }
}

function turn()    {
    var drawnCard = drawCard();
    table.push(drawnCard);
}

function river()    {
    var drawnCard = drawCard();
    table.push(drawnCard);
}

function showDown() {
    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)   {        

        evaluate(i);
        document.write("<br>");   

    }

}

function evaluate(player)  {
    var totalHand = players[player].hand.concat(table);


}


initDeck();
dealCards();
document.write("Player 1: " + players[0].hand[0].name + ' and ' + players[0].hand[1].name + '<br>');
document.write("Player 2: " + players[1].hand[0].name + ' and ' + players[1].hand[1].name + '<br><br>');
flop();
document.write("Flop: " + table[0].name + ', ' + table[1].name + ' and ' + table[2].name + '<br>');
turn();
document.write("Turn: " + table[0].name + ', ' + table[1].name + ', ' + table[2].name + ' and ' + table[3].name + '<br>');
river();
document.write("River: " + table[0].name + ', ' + table[1].name + ', ' + table[2].name + ', ' + table[3].name + ' and ' + table[4].name + '<br>');
showDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about recursion, but you can brute force it with for loops:

```js
var suits = ['Clubs', 'Spades', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds'];
var ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace'];
var deck = [];
var allSets = [];
var combinations = [{
  name: 'Straight flush',
  test: function(cards) {
    //All must have same suit
    if (cards.some(function(card) {
        return card.suit != cards[0].suit;
      })) {
      return false;
    }
    //Is consecutive
    var arr = cards
      .map(function(card) {
        return card.rank;
      })
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
      });
    return Math.abs(arr[0] - arr[arr.length - 1]) <= 4;
  },
  success: function() {
    //return a score modifier
    return 100;
  }
}];
//Card class
var Card = (function() {
  function Card(suit, rank) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.id = Card._id++;
  }
  return Card;
}());
Card._id = 0;
//Build deck
for (var suit = 0; suit < suits.length; suit++) {
  for (var rank = 0; rank < ranks.length; rank++) {
    deck.push(new Card(suit, rank));
  }
}
//Find sets
for (var index0 = 0; index0 < deck.length; index0++) {
  for (var index1 = index0 + 1; index1 < deck.length; index1++) {
    for (var index2 = index1 + 1; index2 < deck.length; index2++) {
      for (var index3 = index2 + 1; index3 < deck.length; index3++) {
        for (var index4 = index3 + 1; index4 < deck.length; index4++) {
          var set = [deck[index0], deck[index1], deck[index2], deck[index3], deck[index4]];
          var score = 0;
          for (var index = 0; index < set.length; index++) {
            score += set[index].rank;
          }
          for (var combinationIndex = 0; combinationIndex < combinations.length; combinationIndex++) {
            var combination = combinations[combinationIndex];
            if (combination.test(set)) {
              score += combination.success();
              break;
            }
          }
          allSets.push({
            set: set.slice(0),
            score: score
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
//Sort sets
allSets = allSets
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.score - a.score;
  });
//Display 100 best sets
console.log("100 best:", allSets
  .slice(0, 100).map(function(a) {
    a.set = a.set
      .map(function(b) {
        return suits[b.suit] + "" + ranks[b.rank];
      })
      .join(", ");
    return a;
  }));
```

Just extends the combinations list with any test you wish to run.